# Stack Overflow logo alt text incorrect?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, accessibility, alt-text

I just noticed that the Stack Overflow logo image `alt` text is "logo homepage".

The [W3C WCAG 1.0 guidlines](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#image-text-equivalent) state that every non text element should contain a text equivalent. This isn't very specific but I would have thought that at least the word "Stack Overflow" should appear in the `alt` text somewhere, seeing as the image does contain that text.

Maybe the alt text should be "Stack Overflow logo"?

Comment: Where is the turtle?

Comment: @random: what?

Comment: `LOGO` is a programming language where you move the `turtle` around the screen to draw pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sighted, but for what it's worth, "stackoverflow logo" makes more sense to me than "logo homepage".

Is the word "homepage" there to indicate that clicking it goes to the homepage? I already expect that clicking on the logo will bring me back to the homepage, and I'd probably have developed the same expectation if blind so, if my reader tells me that the first link is "stackowverflow logo", I'd expect that clicking it would bring me to the stackoverflow page.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer the alt text to be "[site] homepage", as then the resulting link text reads as, say, "Stack Overflow homepage" which is an accurate description of what is being linked to.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it's a logo is likely of very little interest to a non-sighted user. All they need to know is whatever information the image conveys. In effect, it's conveying the main heading of the site, which is not present in any text. Therefore, `alt="stackoverflow"` (or `alt="stack overflow"`) is probably most appropriate.

@redtuna: I believe that the fact that there's a link wrapped around the logo, which links to the home page, should be communicated via the `title` of the link. This information is specific to the link, not the image.

Comment: FWIW, I notice that this is actually what's been implemented :)

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: Note that for an image-only link the `alt` of the `img` element should describe the link target, not the `title` of the `a` element ([details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19776398/1591669)).